# Get POST Data From Firefox History?

Tags: firefox, http

I am a writer/blogger. Yesterday, I wrote a long blog post on Html 5 Editor in Firefox and click the save button. I got some error. When I click the back button, all of my blog content vanished. Is there is a way to recover the posted data from Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no there is no way to retrieve the data.  The POST data only exists for as long as the session is active.  Once you have left the domain or closed the browser, the session data has been lost.

Comment: I have not closed the browser and left the domain yet. What I can I do?

Comment: You can take a look on Firebug (IE & chrome) which will possibly allow you to view session post data if it is still active.  If not, you've lost it - sorry

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers keep post data in memory, hitting F5 after an error occured will retransmit this data and any plugin capable of inspecting headers (such as livehttpheaders for firefox, firebug,...) will allow you to copy this lengthy text.

Using the back button, some browsers preserve the sent data and show a non-empty form, ready to be edited again.
However, [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) says:

> a history mechanism is meant to show exactly what the user saw at
>   the time when the resource was retrieved.